# java extension mechanism

Tags: java, classpath

I've created a .jar containing some packages and I tried to put it into

```
c:\jdk\jre\lib\ext
```

but the java commnand does not find the package

If I, instead, put the .jar into

```
c:\jre\lib\ext
```

all works!

Why? The SUN's tutorial says that both the locations are good!

I saw that the extension mechanism works only for VM but not for the compiling process so
for compilation if I want to use external packages I must compile with the -cp flag

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

JREs only use their own `lib/ext` directory. So you need to put the jars into the `lib/ext` directory of every JRE you want the library to work with. Using `lib/ext` is generally a bad idea.

I believe to get it to work with your compiler, you will need to place the jars in `c:\jdk\lib\ext`, not `c:\jdk\jre\lib\ext`.

Comment: look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html 
the dir is jdk\jre\lib\ext and not, like you say, c:\jdk\lib\ext

Answer (score 1):

If I'm to take your two locations literally (i.e. no typo); a more likely scenario is that your JAVA_HOME isn't pointing to the JRE inside the JDK (c:\jdk\jre); but rather to a JRE somewhere outside your JDK (c:\jre).

As tackline posted above, you do in fact need to put the library in each and every JRE that you want to actually use, too. (Try installing Java3D sometime and observe what happens).